# How do I turn off VoLTE via adb?

Tags: android, adb

The way to turn off VoLTE through the UI is Settings > Cellular Networks > and toggle "Enhanced 4G LTE Mode".

How do I do this same action through adb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run:

```
adb shell settings put global volte_vt_enabled 0
```

You will see the settings UI toggle off the "Enhanced 4G LTE Mode" setting, but this won't actually turn off the setting.

You then need to run:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.telephony.action.CARRIER_CONFIG_CHANGED
```

If you want this to persist between reboots, you can run:

```
adb shell setprop persist.mtk.volte.enable 0
```

Comment: on first command I get "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denial: writing to settings requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"